# split a long string of arguments after delimiter

Tags: bash

I have a very long string with http addresses which are separated by the column "|" ie

```
http://bla.com|http://blabla.com|...
```

how would it be possible in bash to have something like

```
http://bla.com
http://blabla.com
```

thanks

-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
 echo "http://bla.com|http://blabla.com" | tr '|' '\n'
```